# Stripe Address Elements onChange event not firing bug

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I have a very strange bug in my react development environment running on localhost port 3000 in which the stripe AddressElement from react-stripe-js onChange event does not fire unless I make a change to the text editor and save .  I am running a React App and capturing the address details.  At first render there is no onChange event firing when user enters in address details, however if I go back to my text editor in VS Code and add a space anywhere in the code and save which causes it to update, then the event will fire perfectly capturing all details as intended.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {useLocation, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";
import { Elements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import CheckoutForm from "./CheckoutForm";
import {AddressElement} from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import { parseCartToObject } from '../helpers';




const Checkout = () => {

    const location = useLocation();

    const stripePromise = loadStripe('testkey-removed-for-this-post');
    const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] = useState("");


    useEffect(() => {
        // Create PaymentIntent as soon as the page loads
        fetch("http://localhost:4242/create-payment-intent", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          body: JSON.stringify({ 
            amount:location.state.userCart.totalCost
          }),
        })
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((data) => {
            setClientSecret(data.clientSecret) 
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log('error', err);
          })
      }, []);

    return(
        <div className='checkout'>
            <h1 className='checkout-heading'>checkout</h1>
            <p>total to pay £{location.state.userCart.totalCost}</p>
            <Link className='checkout-btn' to="/">back to basket</Link>
            {clientSecret && (
              <Elements 
              options={{appearance:{theme:'stripe'},clientSecret:clientSecret}} stripe={stripePromise}>
                    <AddressElement options={{mode: 'shipping'}} 
                    onChange={(event) => {  
                      console.log(event);
                      if (event.complete) {
                        const address = event.value
                        let finalCart = parseCartToObject();
                        finalCart.username = address.name;
                        finalCart.address = address.address;
                        localStorage.setItem('userCart',JSON.stringify(finalCart));
                        console.log('address and name added to cart'); 
                      }

                    }}
                    />
                    <CheckoutForm />
               </Elements>
            )}
        </div>
    )
};

export default Checkout;
```

Answer (score 1):

I added a setTimeout function in the Elements tag which sets useState variable loaded to true in which case the onChange event fires as normal.  If no state changes when Elements and all inner components render, the onChange event does not fire.

```
<Elements 
              options={{appearance:{theme:'stripe'},clientSecret:clientSecret}} stripe={stripePromise}>
                {  // SetTimeout used to fix a bug as onChange event on AddressElement does not fire unelss some state changes
                setTimeout(() => {
                  setLoaded(true);
                },500)
                }
                    <AddressElement options={{mode: 'shipping'}} 
                    onChange={(event) => {  
                      console.log(event);
                      if (event.complete) {
                        const address = event.value
                        let finalCart = parseCartToObject();
                        finalCart.username = address.name;
                        finalCart.address = address.address;
                        localStorage.setItem('userCart',JSON.stringify(finalCart));
                        console.log('address and name added to cart'); 
                      }
                    }}
                    />
                    <CheckoutForm />
</Elements>
```